# Regex split on white space except ones with a colon

Tags: regex

I have the following string

`s = "hiack: 18   seqno: 37   cwnd: 20.000 ssthresh: 200 dupacks: 0"`

I would like to use a regex to split that line up so it becomes

`s = ['hiack: 18' 'seqno: 37' 'cwnd: 20.000' 'ssthresh: 200' 'dupacks: 0']`

What regex pattern should I use to achive this?

Edit: I am using python incase that makes a difference

Comment: Are you sure that each key/values are not separated with a tabulation?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte They are seperated by spaces

Comment: In this case instead of trying to split, try to match each key/value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
% nodejs
> s = "hiack: 18   seqno: 37   cwnd: 20.000 ssthresh: 200 dupacks: 0"
'hiack: 18   seqno: 37   cwnd: 20.000 ssthresh: 200 dupacks: 0'
> s.split(/\b\s+\b/)
[ 'hiack: 18',
  'seqno: 37',
  'cwnd: 20.000',
  'ssthresh: 200',
  'dupacks: 0' ]
>
```

Even if you use anything else than JS, you can pick up the *regex*.

It works using `\b` aka *word boundaries*

Comment: Thank you. This works for me. Can you explain why this works? i.e Why wont it pick up the spaces that have colons in them

Comment: Added explanations